# Using Maximum Modulus Principle/Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

I stumbled upon this question and am trying to solve it:

If $f$ is analytic in the unit disk and $f$ has a zero of order $n$ at $0$, then $|f(z)| \leq |z|^n$ for all $|z| \leq 1$.

I have tried solving this by letting $f(z) = z^n g(z)$ where $g(0) \neq 0$. Then playing with MMP or SL but have not made much progress. I have seen questions posted about this before but they all seem to have the additional assumption that $|f(z)| \leq 1$. In this case of course the problem would be simpler. However, can I deduce this from what I am given?

Comment: Of course you need the additional assumption that $|f(z)| \le 1$ for $z \le 1$. Otherwise there is the trivial counterexample $f(z) = 2z$, which has a zero of order 1 at $z =0$.

Comment: or for that matter the trivial counterexample $f(z)=2$ which has a zero of order $0$

Comment: @GregMartin A "zero of order $0$" isn't usually counted as a zero.

Comment: Agreed—but it is the base case of the induction on the order of the zero, so ultimately where the result comes from! (Schwarz's lemma, the $n=1$ case, is itself so derived from the maximum modulus principle, the "$n=0$ case".)